# What do you call the number you add to a decimal to get 1?

Tags: terminology

If you have a number that is between 0 and 1, what would you call the number that you add to it to get 1? Is there a specific term for it? I was under the impression it had a name like inverse or reciprocal or something like that, although I know it is neither of those.

In probability, if the chances of something happening are 0.2, then 0.8 is the complementary probability, but I'm looking for a more general term.

Comment: I don't think it has a name. I haven't heard of one, at least.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have also never heard of any specific name applied to such a value.

Comment: I only know the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of a number, but that's also not really what you want.

Comment: In a ***very*** loose sense it be okay to call in a "compliment" (to get an integer value).  But compliment will have other meanings in other contexts.  I think if you called it a "fractional compliment" most would surmise in context what you meant.  ANd there's nothing wrong with *explaining* what you mean.

Comment: Maybe you can invent a name for it if you need to use it a lot. How about "padding"? e.g. For $0.2$, we pad $0.8$ to get $1$.

Comment: @fleablood *Complement* with an *e* I hope! *Compliment* would be telling the number how wonderful it is, not subtracting it from $1$ . . .

Comment: If you want it to subtract from 1 willingly you'd *better* be nice to it!

Comment: @fleablood Good point!